# Planetarium sky animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to make the inside sphere effect, like planetarium, where I will show not stars, but planets.

The obvious way is to use sphere and place camera inside. But I wish to make animation from the spherical surface to the flat surface.

Also I wish to shift sky (planets) by X and Y to emulate user scrolling action.

The closest way that I found is use the particle emitter and changing the "Jittering Amo".

[image]

But it can't be animated.

**How can I achieve this effects**: the planetarium effects (like Google Sky Map) and animate the surface from the sphere to the flatness (like Google Maps)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe instead of having all those planets physically on the sphere, render them out in advance as a sky map, map it to a sphere, and when transitioning from 3D to 2D flatten one side of the sphere. You can animate the UV map with the AnimAll add-on, so that may help. This is rough theory though, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood your question, but have you tried panorama camera mode in cycles? There is Fisheye Equidistant projection, it will spherize you render

Just spread your planets with particles in a volume, and then move your camera towards it, it will correctly distort your image for FullDome projection